# Capitalization and Hyphenation in Python

Tags: python

I am self-learning Python in a online class, and there are one question that I cannot figure out:

If I want the user to enter a string. For example:

The Input string = "born on a monday in the autumn of 1997, i will celebrate my twenty Fifth birthday in the coming September by eating two third of a cheese cake."
The Output String = "Born on a Monday in the Autumn of 1997, I will celebrate my Twenty-fifth birthday in the coming September by eating two-third of a cheese cake."

It requires:

capitalised including (i) Day of the week; (ii) Month; and (iii) Seasons;

hyphenation the Ordinal numbers (eg, Forty-first, Ninety-second, etc) and Fractions (eg, half-, quarter-, one-third, three-fourteenth, …., up to N-twentieth)

Capitalize the first non-space character in the string and the character after a period, exclamation mark or question mark

So far I only have:

```
import re

def uppercase(matchobj):
    return matchobj.group(0).upper()

#Capitalize the first non-space character in the string
#Capitalize the first non-space character after a period, exclamation mark or question mark
#Capitalize a lowercase “i” if it is preceded by a space and followed by a space, full stop, exclamation mark, question mark or apostrophe.
def capitalize(s):
    return re.sub('^([a-z])|[\.|\?|\!]\s*([a-z])|\s+i(?![a-z])', uppercase, s)
    
def main(): #
    s = input("Enter string: ") #reads a string from the user
    capitalized = capitalize(s) #capitalizes user's string using the function
    print("Capitalization of letter strings:", capitalized) #displays the result

#Call the main function
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way out. Somewhere in your program you will have to write something similar to:

```py
ordinal_numbers = [
    "first",
    "second",
    "third",
    "fourth",
    "fifth",
    "sixth",
    # ...
    "tenth",
    "twentieth",
    # ...
    "hundredth",
    "thousandth",
    # ...
]

week_days = [
    "sunday",
    "monday",
    # ...
]

months = [
    "january"
    # ...
]
```

Then you will have to replace all instances with the appropriate things. There really isn't a better way...

You could of course use regular expressions for this, but they will have to be huge so I think if readability is any factor using plain string replacement and parsing will leave you better off

Comment: hi @Zachiah, is it like the function of "dictionary"?
I try to use the easy way to solve this problem, could I change my syntax in this way:

sentence = input("input your sentences: ").split()
for word in range(len(sentence)):
    if sentence[word] == "i":
        sentence[word] = "I"
    for character in sentence[word]:
        print(word, character)

Comment: Yeah you need a loop over that but you'll have to write all the things you want to replace somewhere in your code I don't think a dictionary could help you much